# How is machine learning incorporated into search engine design?

Tags: search, language-agnostic, lucene, machine-learning, search-engine

I am currently building a small in-house search engine based on Apache Lucene. Its purpose is simple - based on some keywords, it will suggest some articles written internally within our company. I am using a fairly standard TF-IDF scoring as a base metric and built my own scoring mechanism on top it. All of these seem to be working excellent except for some corner cases where the ranking seems messed up.

So what I am planning on doing is to add a small Relevant/Not Relevant link to the search results page so that users can click on one of those depending on their perception of whether that result should have been included in the first place.

## My Idea

1. Treat these Relevant/Not Relevant as labels and create a training data.
2. Use this data to train a classifier (such as SVM)
3. Incorporate this model into the search engine i.e., every new result will pass through the classifier and will be assigned a label on whether it is relevant or not.

This approach seems intuitive to me but am not sure whether it will work in practice. I have two specific questions:

1. What all features should I extract?
2. Is there a better way to integrate the machine learning component into the search engine? My final goal is to "learn" the ranking function based on both business logic as well as user feedback.

Comment: I did something like this once and the users hated it so I turned it off. The problem was user behavior. Users adapted to the weaknesses in the search results by changing their terms, and then they would keep re-using those terms. The system responded adjusting the ranking of items and those favorited terms started to produce different results. This pisted off users. Learning doesn't mean it's smarter ;)

Comment: Here is an implementation using elasticsearch and angularjs - also contains the explanations you need - https://machinelearningblogs.com/2016/12/12/how-to-build-a-search-engine-part-1/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> (1) What all features should I extract?

First, realize that you're not classifying documents. You're classifying (document, query) pairs, so you should extract features that express how well they match.

The standard approach in [learning to rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank) is to run the query against various search engine setups (e.g. tf-idf, BM-25, etc.) and then train a model on the similarity scores, but for a small, domain-specific SE, you could have features such as

- For each term, a boolean that indicates whether the term occurs in both the query and the document. Or maybe not a boolean, but the tf-idf weights of those query terms that actually occur in the document.
- Various overlap metrics such as [Jaccard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) or Tanimoto.

> (2) Is there a better way to integrate the machine learning component into the search engine? My final goal is to "learn" the ranking function based on both business logic as well as user feedback.

This is a very broad question, and the answer depends on how much effort you want to put in. The first improvement that comes to mind is that you should use not the binary relevance judgements from the classifier, but its real-valued decision function, so that you can actually do ranking instead of just filtering. For an SVM, the decision function is the signed distance to the hyperplane. Good machine learning packages have an interface for getting the value of that.

Beyond that, look into pairwise and listwise learning to rank; what you're suggesting is the so-called pointwise approach. IIRC, pairwise works a lot better in practice. The reason is that with pairwise ranking, you need much fewer clicks: instead of having users label documents as relevant/irrelevant, you only give them the "relevant" button. Then you learn a binary classifier on triples (document1, document2, query) that tells whether document1 is **more relevant** to the query than document2, or vice versa. When a user labels, say, document 4 in the ranking as relevant, that gives you six samples to learn from:

- document4 > document3
- document4 > document2
- document4 > document1
- document1 < document4
- document2 < document4
- document3 < document4

so you get the negatives for free.

(These are all just suggestions, I haven't tried any of this. I just happen to have worked in a research group where people investigated learning to rank. I did do a presentation of someone else's paper for a reading group once, maybe the [slides](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~buitinck/presentation/semi-l2r/) can be of help.)

Comment: +1 Thank you. This is the second time you helped me out! Let me take a couple of hours to digest this. :)

Comment: That's an excellent answer, I'd just like to suggest a minor tweak. From an ux perspective, you're much more likely to get users to score a result by using a "irrelevant" button than a "relevant" button. Who sticks around to score a result when they've found what they're looking for? They're *much* more likely to hit a button that looks like an "opportunity to complain" when they haven't found what they wanted, because improving the system at that point is actually aligned with their current goal.

Comment: tl;dr If you're going to use just one input, make it "irrelevant", people are more likely to click it when they're frustrated.

Comment: What would be the "listwise" approach? Also, did you mean 3 or 6 examples for free? (The last 3 seem to be just a repetition of the first 3?)